# Automatically obtain feature equations

Tags: differential-equations, eigenvalues

How can I automatically obtain the characteristic equation of a second-order differential equation given any expression?

Assuming a second-order differential equation is given as follows：

```
x''[t] + x'[t] + 16 x[t] == 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your equation has wrong syntax. `x^\[Prime]\[Prime])` should be written like: `x''` (not back ticks and no superscript). Then we can get the characteristic equation by:

```
eq = x''[t] + Derivative[1][x][t] + 16 x[t] == 0;
eq /. {x[t] -> 1, x'[t] -> x, x''[t] -> x^2}

16 + x + x^2 == 0
```

Comment: Sir, thank you for your answer! Your answer has helped me. And I have corrected my expression writing in the original problem.

Comment: Or, if higher derivatives are present `{x[t] -> 1, Derivative[n_][x][t] :> x^n}`

Comment: @rhermansr Yep, thanks for your inspired ideas.